# How to run a perl script(which i cant modify) from another perl script

Tags: regex, perl

I used `system("/usr/bin/perl abcd.pl");`

But its aborting saying **Can't locate JSON.pm in @INC**.

Please Help me here.

```
perl -v
```

perl -v

This is perl, v5.8.8 built for i386-freebsd-64int
(with 1 registered patch, see perl -V for more detail)

Copyright 1987-2006, Larry Wall

Perl may be copied only under the terms of either the Artistic License or the
GNU General Public License, which may be found in the Perl 5 source kit.

Complete documentation for Perl, including FAQ lists, should be found on
this system using "man perl" or "perldoc perl".  If you have access to the
Internet, point your browser at http://www.perl.org/, the Perl Home Page.

```
grep '#!' abcl.pl
```

#!/volume/perl/bin/perl

Comment: which operating system your using?

Comment: well, do you have JSON.pm installed on the system? If so, where?

Comment: please provide actually what your code and what you tried

Comment: my OS is unix. JSON.pm is present. While i run the script manually from its location, it runs fine. But via another script, it throws the error.

Comment: What is `which perl`? If it's different from `/usr/bin/perl`: `perl -E'say for @INC'`, `/usr/bin/perl -E'say for @INC'`

Comment: @Ram **My os is FreeBSD 8.1**. @amon.. i use simply this command `system("/usr/bin/perl xyz.pl")` . I dont know if there is perl -E.

Comment: you can also use: `type perl` - shows where is your default perl located, and `grep '#!' abcd.pl` for check, if it has another path... and like...

Comment: @FlankingKnight The commands I suggested were meant to be run in your shell: `which perl` tells us which file will be executed when requesting the `perl` program. The `perl -E'…'` commands show us the directories where perl will look for modules.

Comment: @amon it is `/usr/bin/perl`

Comment: @FlankingKnight - __EDIT__ your question and add the result of the next 3 commands: `perl -MJSON -e';'` and the result of `perl -V` and `grep '#!' abcd.pl`

Comment: make that `grep -En '^#!|INC' abcd.pl`

Comment: @amon... `1:#!/volume/perl/bin/perl` this was the output. what does it mean?

Comment: @FlankingKnight That means it found a match for that regex on the 1st line. Even though you execute the script with `/usr/bin/perl`, when it sees that line, it will execute the script via `/volume/perl/bin/perl` instead, which is a different perl interpreter.

Comment: @amon so, i need to use `/volume/perl/bin/perl` or something else needs to be done.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `do 'abc.pl';` instead.  That will execute the other Perl script within the current process, rather than starting a new one.  It uses less overhead, and you will be sure that it is using the same environment that your script is.  This isn't a completely foolproof suggestion, as it is possible that the script could do things that interfere with your script.  But if it works, it's a cleaner solution, in my opinion.

That said, the problem was probably that the version of Perl you called is different than the one that has JSON.pm installed, as Amon suggested.

Less likely is that the script itself is doing something funny with `@INC` (such as hardcoding it to a particular directory) that would stop it from working.

Comment: Another work around worked for me.
i used `./abc.pl -sr` in the directory instead of `perl abc.pl -sr`. it executed the script.
Can anyone please explain how it worked.

Answer (score 1):

When perl executes a script which has a shebang, it tries to be extra helpful and invoke the interpreter specified on the shebang. Here, you want to execute the script with `/usr/bin/perl`, but it sees `/volume/perl/bin/perl` and decides to load that instead.

I don't know of any way to override this “feature”.

It might be simpler to install the JSON module for `/volume/perl/bin/perl`:

```
$ /volume/perl/bin/perl -MCPAN -e 'CPAN::Shell->install("JSON")'
```

As noted by dan1111, you could also opt to not execute the script with a different process, and swap `system` out for `do`:

```
do "abcd.pl";
```

Or you could do both:

```
system '/usr/bin/perl', '-e', 'do "abcd.pl"';
```

but this is getting silly.